# How to retrieve a byte array from and filename Ext JS uploadFileForm

Tags: extjs, arrays

I have an `uploadFileForm` and a save button to submit an upload. How do I retrieve a byte array and a filename on save button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the file name using `fileUploadField.getValue()`.  You may have to parse the string to get just the file name.

To get the contents, you can try using the HTML5 File Reader API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.  The only other option is to actually submit the form and handle the file on the server.